# How can I move a board piece?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, move, actionlistener

I am making a board game and having trouble moving them. The piece will move according to the dice result. Below is what i attempt to do but it does not work.(from button[].addActionListener(new ActionListener()) Note: I have used ImageIcon to represent my pieces. Any help?

```
    //Puts the player 1 piece on button 1,3,5,7,9 and player 2 piece on button 2,4,6,8,10 
    if ((btnNumber - 1) < 10) 
    { 
        if (((btnNumber - 1) % 2) == 0) 
        { 
            buttons[btnNumber - 1].setIcon(piece1); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            buttons[btnNumber - 1].setIcon(piece2); 
        } 
    } 
    centerPanel.add(buttons[btnNumber - 1]); 
} 

frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: What is `button[]`?  Where is it defined?

Comment: Set the grid[][] value where the piece is currently located to EMPTY, and set the piece's new position in that grid to the piece being moved.

Comment: Also `buttons[]==ImageIcon("piece1")` will always be false: you compare an array of JButton with an image. Not even sure what you are trying to achieve on that line.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @assylias third line, its an array of buttons

Comment: @UmzzMo third line is `buttons` with an `s`. So not the same variable. You should post code that compiles at least.

Comment: @assylias It wont work anyways because the error says class expected.

Comment: If you don't want your code on the internet, don't post it in the first place.  Once it's posted, it's part of the question and it stays for context.  Rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though there are some basic things you haven't quite grasped yet.  Here are some suggestions for getting closer to your goal:

1. `button[].addActionListener` is a nonsensical statement.  You can't add an action listener to an entire array at once.  Perhaps you meant to say `buttons[btnNumber - 1].addActionListener` and place it inside the `for` loop.
2. `buttons[]==ImageIcon("piece1")` is also a meaningless statement (it should not even have compiled).  You could try `buttons[btnNumber - 1] == ImageIcon("piece1")`, though there is an easier way to do this (#3).
3. Instead of determining the location of the piece based on whether it equals an image icon instance, why not have variables `piece1Location` and `piece2Location` that you keep updated as the pieces move.  Then you would know instantly where the pieces are, and your logic would simplify to `if (btnNumber - 1 == piece1Location)`
4. In Java, arrays start at index `0`.  The cleanest way to work with an array in Java with a `for` loop is to start your indexing variable at `0` as well, and change your comparison from `<=` to `<`.  With the following `for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)`, you don't have to keep saying `btnNumber - 1`.
5. The organization of your code is a little confusing and tightly integrated between model and presentation.  You should seek to separate logic dealing with showing the board and pieces (presentation) from logic dealing with the mechanics of the game (rolling dice, moving pieces, etc.).  This will help you immensely in maintaining your code and keeping track of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It really makes sense but the problem is that i have 5 pieces for each player. They can move any of the 5. So how would piece1Location work when there is 5 pieces each?

Comment: It sounds like you need another class, like `GameBoardState`, which keeps track of the players and their pieces in an array.  As I mention in point #5, you should develop a model of the structure of your game separately from the presentation.  In fact, one of the best ways to do this would be to develop the game entirely to be run in the command-line first.  Once you have that working, then build a UI for the game.  It may sound like over-kill at this point, but it will help a lot in the long run in managing your project as it grows in size and scope.

Comment: Also, how will you handle the situation where multiple pieces are currently on the same board location (i.e., button)?  How are you going to determine whether a move is valid or invalid?  How are you going to determine if someone has won the game?  Have you thought about these things as well?  It is helpful to think about the whole scope of the project on a piece of paper and jot down a high-level plan before ever writing the first line of code.  Design should be done on paper, not in the IDE.

Comment: But to answer your original question (how can I move a board piece), your code looks like it should do it once you've resolved the compiler errors.

Comment: how can I get it to move? I cant seem to figure it out